# Defining a queue datastructure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am just trying to learn JavaScript. I want to design a queue which takes the following format:

```
[{(0,0),0}], [{(0,1),1}], [{(0,2),2}]
```

So I tried to define the queue in the following way, but obviously it's not correct

```
var queue = [{}] ;
```

Comment: JS-Objects (`{}`) are key:value-based. You could use arrays (`[]`) if all you need are the values?

Comment: I usually like to create new types to define complex data-structures. `[new User(new Position(0,0), 0), ..]` (or whatever it may be) is usually easier for me to read past a very trivial depth.

Comment: And then in your queue you would keep these Objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, there is no "couple" data-strucuture in JS, so your `(0,1)` must be an array `[0,1]` , an object: `{x: 0, y: 1}` or a custom type (see below).

In javascript, structures aren't strongly typed, so you just have to define if the root is an array or an object. In this case, it seems to be an array.

```
var queue = [];
```

Then, push in the queue what you need. For example : *(I invented the field names, fits them to your use case)*

```
var element1 = {coords: [0, 0], val: 0 };
queue.push(element1);
var element2 = {coords: [0, 1], val: 1 };
queue.push(element2);
```

Like I said, you can use another representation, like: `[[0,0], 0]`, or define a custom type (Object-oriented).

```
function MyType(coords, val) {
  this.coords = coords;
  this.val = val;
}

function Couple(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

queue.push(new MyType(new Couple(1, 2), 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

For the queue you want to use an `array` for keeping the values

```
var myQueue = []  //Empty array
```

Add something to the queue by pushing it onto the array

```
myQueue.push(new Person(...))
```

Fetch something from the queue by shifting it out of the array

```
var nextInLine = myQueue.shift()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build queue as follows:

```
function Queue () {
 this.dataStore = [];
 this.enqueue = enqueue;
 this.dequeue = dequeue;
 this.front = front;
 this.back = back;
 this.toString = toString;
 this.empty = empty;
}

// Insetion
function enqueue(element){
 this.dataStore.push(element);
}

// Deletion
function dequeue(){
 this.dataStore.shift();
}

// front
function front(){
 return this.dataStore[0];
}

//back
function back(){
 return this.dataStore[this.dataStore.length-1];
}

//toString
function toString(){
  var retStr = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < this.dataStore.length; i++){
    retStr = retStr + this.dataStore[i]
  }
  return retStr;
 }

//empty
function empty(){
 if(this.dataStore.length === 0) {
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

Now use it as a constructor method, var q = new Queue().